# Is there a way to make use of the Bluetooth 5.0 capabilities of the Movesense device?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, movesense

Is there a way to make use of the Bluetooth 5.0 capabilities of the Movesense device?
I need a 100m advertising packet range, but am only getting about 20m.

Comment: This is a question you should ask the people at Movesense. In this forum the question is quite off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the bluetooth radio chip which Movesense sensor uses does not support the Bluetooth 5 "long range" mode.

*Full disclaimer: I work for the Movesense team*